# Why it asks the same but in the code theres only 1 printf()?

Tags: c

Im sorry but im just learning c, probably its easy to fix but i dont know how

In the code i just have 1 printf but in the terminal shows the same question 2 times. But finally the result is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double lfDemanaTaxa(){
    double i;
    double d;

    printf("Quant es la taxa interes nominal?\n");
    scanf("%lf",&i);
    d = i/100;

    return d;
}
double lfDemanaMensualitat(){
    double n;

    scanf("%lf",&n);

    return n;
}

int main(){
    double a,b,c,TAE;
    a = (1+lfDemanaTaxa()/lfDemanaMensualitat());
    b = pow(a,lfDemanaMensualitat());
    c = b -1;
    TAE = c * 100;
    printf("El TAE total es %.2lf%% \n", TAE);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: here you can see it questions the same and i put the same number]

Comment: BTW your output does not match your program.

Comment: And when you fix your output to match your program, please remember:  **Never ever** show plain text output as a graphic. Text is no artwork.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call the `lfDemanaMensualitat()` function twice, and it does one call to `printf()`, so of course you're going to have two print-outs.

If you wanted to only call it once and store the value, you can something like this:

```
const double t = lfDemanaMensualitat();
const double a = (1 + lfDemanaTaxa()) / t;
const double b = pow(a, t);
```

And then compute `c` and `TAE` like you already do. This just saves the result of `lfDemanaMensualitat()` in a temporary variable called `t`.

By the way you should know that `scanf()` can fail, if the user enters things that don't match the specified conversion. You must check the return value to make sure it succeeded before relying on the input.